# how to parse XML as a PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have an application that allows the upload of a .xml file that I would like to parse as php however when doing so I receive the error:

> uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in.......

I'm currently accessing the .xml from a folder within the application using the simplexml_load_file function.

I know that this does return the contents of the file as I can see them if I use print_r function on the page

The bit that I don't seem to know is how and where I add the xml tags

If I hard code the contents of the xml into the variable $xmlstr and suuround that by the XMl tags everything does work as I want it to.

As soon as I try to store the XML into a variable I receive the following:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 3: parser error
>   : Start tag expected, '<' not found in........
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): in .......
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in .......
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: String could not be parsed as XML in
>   .....
>
> SimpleXMLElement->__construct('\n\n') #1 {main} thrown in.......

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("output.xml");
$array = (array) $xml;
$xmlstr = $xml;
?>
```

I'd like to be able to parse the contents of $xmlstr

the contents of the xml file are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<robot rpa="false" generated="20190905 22:17:06.914" generator="Robot 
3.1.2 (Python 2.7.10 on darwin)">
<suite source="../testXML.robot" id="s1" name="testXML">
<test id="s1-t1" name="[TC001] TEST 001">
<kw name="Open Browser" library="SeleniumLibrary">
<doc></doc>
<arguments>
<arg></arg>
<arg></arg>
</arguments>
<msg timestamp="20190905 22:17:07.774" level="INFO"></msg>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20190905 22:17:10.930" 
starttime="20190905 22:17:07.774"></status>
</kw>
<kw name="Close Browser" library="SeleniumLibrary">
<doc></doc>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20190905 22:17:11.062" 
starttime="20190905 22:17:10.933"></status>
</kw>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20190905 22:17:11.062" critical="yes" 
starttime="20190905 22:17:07.773"></status>
</test>

<test id="s1-t2" name="[TC002] TEST 002">
<kw name="Open Browser" library="SeleniumLibrary">
<doc></doc>
<arguments>
<arg></arg>
<arg></arg>
</arguments>
<msg timestamp="20190905 22:17:11.064" level="INFO"></msg>
<kw name="Capture Page Screenshot" library="SeleniumLibrary">
<doc></doc>
<msg timestamp="20190905 22:17:11.088" level="INFO"></msg>
<status status="PASS" endtime="20190905 22:17:11.088" starttime="20190905 22:17:11.087"></status>
</kw>
<msg timestamp="20190905 22:17:11.142" level="FAIL">
</msg>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20190905 22:17:11.142" starttime="20190905 22:17:11.063"></status>
</kw>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20190905 22:17:11.142" critical="yes" starttime="20190905 22:17:11.063">
</status>
</test>
<status status="FAIL" endtime="20190905 22:17:11.143" starttime="20190905 22:17:06.915"></status>
</suite>
</robot>
```

if I copy the contents of the file to this it works:

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("output.xml");
$array = (array) $xml;
$xmlstr = <<<XML *file contents copied to here*

XML;
?>
```

Comment: Can you show an example file which causes this problem.

Comment: Using the sample file, the code runs OK.  Are you sure it is this code that is failing and not something else?

Comment: do I need get it looking something like this <<<XML $xml XML;

Comment: If you want the XML as a string - `$xml=simplexml_load_file("output.xml"); $xmlstr =$xml->asXML();`

Comment: Fundamental point of note in the question title: You are parsing XML *in* (via) PHP, not *as* PHP.